# Create Issue in Github from JIRA ticket

Tags: git, github, jira

I'm trying to see if there's an integration to be able to create an issue in Github from a JIRA ticket. Basically creating an issue in a particular repository with title and subtitle from JIRA.

I'm trying to find the best way to communicate this two tools because Product team uses JIRA and Dev team uses Github.

I know that there's a DVCS connector that can links commits into JIRA but what I'm looking for is a "sync" in the other direction.